# Using Hibernate tools for generating .hbm file for a single table from database

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

I wanted to create a Hibernate mapping file from my database for a few tables (not all). How can I achieve this?

When I am trying, it is considering my entire database and crashing without creating any mapping files. It gives me the following error:

> org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinderException: Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated  for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(AG_TXN.sys.check_constraints)'. Same name where generated  for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(AG_TXN.sys.check_constraints)'
>   org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCBinderException: Duplicate class name 'CheckConstraints' generated  for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(AG_TXN.sys.check_constraints)'. Same name where generated  for 'org.hibernate.mapping.Table(AG_TXN.sys.check_constraints)'

Comment: More information is needed to help you, how is it crashing? is there a stack trace or does eclipse just die? Are you following any tutorials? what is your configuration for hibernate-tools? which type of database are you going to?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 with 50+ tables. but i want mapping file for only 1 table out of those 50+ tables.

Comment: i am following this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to setup your `reveng.xml` to only look at specific tables. [The tutorial you mentioned](http://mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools) does not cover this. If you click *Setup* beside `reveng.xml` (seen in step 3 of that tutorial) you will be taken through a wizard to select what you want.

In the end you should expect to have an xml value like so that restricts to a table you want:

```
<schema-selection match-schema="COMMON_SCHEMA" match-table="CITY"/>
```

See the [Red Hat site](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.1/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/hibernaterevengxmlfile.html) for the exact details on the Hibernate `reveng.xml` file.

I believe you are getting that exception because of two tables with the same name.